# Is Ted Shifrin's definition (8-2.3) missing the verbalization of the pullback of the product of a function with a basis?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definition, differential-forms

My question pertains to Ted Shifrin's [Multivariable Mathematics](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Multivariable+Mathematics%3A+Linear+Algebra%2C+Multivariable+Calculus%2C+and+Manifolds-p-9780471526384) Section 8-2.3 Pullbacks.

We are to use the following pieces, given in the definition, to build the pullback $\mathbf{g}^{*}\omega\in\mathcal{A}^{k}\left(U\right)$
of $\omega$ by $\mathbf{g}.$ The symbol $\mathbb{I}$ is a multi-index.
The last four lines are definitive, giving the pullback of a function;
the pullback of a basis 1-form; the pullback of a wedge product; and
the pullback of a sum, respectively:

\begin{align*}
U\subset & \mathbb{R}^{m}\\
\mathbf{g}: & U\to\mathbb{R}^{n}\\
f: & \mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}\\
\mathbf{g}\left(\mathbf{u}\right)= & \mathbf{x}\\
\mathbf{g}^{*}f= & f\circ\mathbf{g}\\
\mathbf{g}^{*}dx_{i}= & dg_{i}=\sum_{j=1}^{m}\frac{\partial g_{i}}{\partial u_{j}}du_{j}\\
\mathbf{g}^{*}\left(dx_{i_{1}}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_{i_{k}}\right)= & dg_{i_{1}}\wedge\dots\wedge dg_{i_{k}}=d\mathbf{g}_{\mathbb{I}}\\
\mathbf{g}^{*}\left(\sum_{\mathbb{I}}f_{\mathbb{I}}d\mathbf{x}_{\mathbb{I}}\right)= & \sum_{\mathbb{I}}\left(f_{\mathbb{I}}\circ\mathbf{g}\right)d\mathbf{g}_{\mathbb{I}}
\end{align*}

Before the final equation he states *"Last, we take the pullback
of the sum to be the sum of the pullbacks."*

It may seem pedantic, but this is mathematics. The last equation appears
to define both the pullback of a sum, as well as the pullback of the
product of a scalar function with a basis k-form. I'm left wondering
if this **is something I should derive from the previous parts of the definition,
or it is simply an unverbalized part of the final part of the definition.
So which is it?**

To my way of thinking, that product "distribution" rule is the
most significant part of the definition.

Comment: You are correct, of course. Indeed, I should have remarked more generally that pullback of any wedge product is the wedge of the pullbacks.